# group timeout on resequencer creates new groups after expiry

Tags: spring-integration

if a resequencer is configured with a group-timeout and the group expires, does it create a new group when a new message arrives to the group or the message is discarded? In case is discarded, we can use the discarded-channel to log them?

thanks in advance

Guzman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Resequencer` removes groups in case of expire and a new message will form a fresh group.

Actually the same is for `Aggregator`, but with new option with Spring Integration 4.1 `expire-groups-upon-timeout` you can change that behaviour.

We should revise it and maybe add to the `Resequencer` as well.

Comment: Hi Arthem! thank you very much for the quick answer! Seeing this, an expiration does not suit as well with the default processMessageGroup on the resequencer. Is there a way to have a scheduler that completes the groups of the resequencer?

Comment: we need something like a resequencer with holes, that release messages when default release strategy is true or after a timeout. The problem is if there are holes in the last messages

Comment: Your use case isn't clear for me right now. I'll take a look one more time tomorrow. Sorry. And meanwhile you maybe share more info on the matter ;-)

Comment: Correct me, if I have missed something else. You need to send `partial` group to the `output-channel` on the `expire`, instead of `discard-channel`, because your `releaseStrategy` returns `false`. In this case you should tie to that last channel as to the normal one. Even with `expire-groups-upon-timeout` option, the group will be discarded anyway.

Comment: I started another post as the original question was answered before. Thanks Arthem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405379/resequencer-with-holes-on-secuence