# resequencer with holes on secuence

Tags: spring-integration

we have an ETL scenario where we use the resequencer.

Messages arrive to the flow with a sequence number that the resequencer uses it to send messages in order, but sometimes messages are discarded previously (because of data validation) and do not arrive to the resequencer. This produces holes in the sequence and resequencer stops sending messages using the default release strategy. To avoid this, we developed a new SequenceTimeoutReleaseStrategy that is a mix between default strategy and TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy from SI. When a message arrives, it checks the timeout and release it if necesary.

All this worked well unless for the last messages that arrive before the timeout and have holes. This messages aren't release by the strategy. We could use a reaper but the secuence may have more than one hole in the sequence so when the resequencer release them it will stop in the first sequence break and remove the group losing the rest of the messages. So, the question is: is there a way to use the resequencer where there can be holes in the sequence?

One solution we have and want to avoid is having a scheduled tasks that removes the messages directly from the message store, but this could be a problem with concurrency and so on, so we prefer other solutions.

Any help is appreciated here

Regards
Guzman

Answer (score 1):

There are two components involved; the release strategy says "something" can be released; the actual decision as to what is released is performed by the `MessageGroupProcessor`. In this case, a `ResequencingMessageGroupProcessor`.

You would need to customize that class to "skip" the hole(s).

You can't wire in a customized MGP using the `<reseequencer/>` namespace, you would have to wire up using `<bean/>` s - a `ResequencingMessageHandler` and a `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean`.

Or use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to change the constructor argument to your custom class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Sorry but with this approach how do you know it is a hole and not a late incoming message?

Comment: With [this change](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3529) a group released by a group timeout or reaper is marked complete (by default). So late arrivers will be discarded immediately. For more sophistication, when using custom release strategy and `MGP` you could add a "marker" message to the group to maintain custom state (or maintain that state somewhere else).

Comment: The problem we had with group-timeout is that if the connection to the message store fails (on getMessage for example), the group is never completed as no messages are expected. What we want is to complete the group ad

Comment: The problem we had with group-timeout is that if the connection to the message store fails (on getMessage for example), the group is never completed as no more messages are expected. What we want is to complete the group after a timeout and be fault tolerant in case of a connection error to the message store. Could you please give me more details about this marker message and how could I use it?

Comment: Also, is it possible to use group-timeout and not discard late arrivers?

Comment: If you set `expire-groups-upon-timeout` to true, the group will be removed and late messages will start a new group which will eventually time out again due to holes (reverts to the current behavior). We have added support for transactions and, in addition, (in 4.1) if the timeout fails for any reason, it is rescheduled to run again after the next timeout. By marker, I mean add a "special" message that contains metadata and have the `MGP` ignore it for the purposes of release.